# On "bei sich" in translation

Tags: grammar, translation

> [Abbas will keinen Israeli mehr bei sich dulden](http://www.zeit.de/politik/ausland/2013-07/abbas-friedensgespraeche-nahost-kerry-obama)

Does that mean, **Abbas doesn't want to tolerate any Israelis any more**?

I think (I'm almost sure, that is) that this is a good rendering of the German original.

However, I still have a problem: do I still need to translate **bei sich** as well? In my opinion, doing so will only make the English version sound more cumbersome.

Comment: I'd say "bei sich" (i.e. in a possible future Palestinian state) is rather important. Also, Abbas is a surname, thus not normally used with an article; and he is _one_ person.

Comment: @chirlu OK, Abbas is a person. I stand corrected. However, you haven't told me (yet) whether my translation is correct or not. Is it correct or not? And you haven't told me either what to do with _bei sich_ in English. Practically, you have not answered any of the two parts of my question. But thanks for telling me Abbas is "one" person.

Comment: Well, you still treat him as a group in your proposed sentence. -- I think I'll just stop attending to your questions.

Comment: @chirlu I just fixed this. I guess indoxica just overlooked that as I didn't even realized it when I read the question.

Comment: @indoxica: you shouldn't snap at someone who tries to help you ask your question.

Comment: It's a question about the english language.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the most important sentence in this article to understand the title is this quote:

> In einer endgültigen Resolution[sic] wollen wir keinen einzigen Israeli – ob Zivilist oder Soldat – **auf unserem Land sehen**.

I highlighted the most significant part in bold.

Abbas (he's the president of Palestine) doesn't want to see any Israeli (civilian and soldier) in his country/on his land.

*Bei sich* refers to his property. Compare: `Bei mir zu Hause` means *at/in my home*.

I think you're translation is incomplete as you omit "bei sich". You just need to add something like *in his country*, and you're fine.
Actually, it's not even just incomplete. It's wrong as you're saying that he does not tolerate any Israeli in general. If this would be true I guess the situation in the middle east would soon be worse as we can expect him to spearhead an attack.

Comment: Nebenbei: "Quelle: ZEIT ONLINE, Reuters,  AP,  AFP,  dpa,  kg"; da hat man viel Auswahl auf der Suche nach dem Spitzenübersetzer, der hier _resolution_ als _Resolution_ wiedergegeben hat. (Verbreiteter englischer Text: _In a final resolution, we would not see the presence of a single Israeli - civilian or soldier - on our lands._)

Comment: @chirlu Good catch. Das kritische Auge liest mit.